# VB templating to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert vb code to C#.

How does the below code convert to c#?

```
Public Class TheBase(Of clTyp As New, cli As Class)
Implements ITheBase(Of clTyp, cli)
```

Comment: You should note that `MyBase` is an invalid name for a class in VB.NET.

Comment: yeah it's just a sample but you have a valid point.

Comment: you can check http://converter.telerik.com/ , great tool . Just one condition - the code should be up to standard for conversion

Comment: How is this class used? Can someone provide a link for what this is? I want to research it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class MyBase<clTyp, cli> : IMyBase<clType,cli>
where clTyp : new()
where cli : class
```

Further you can use some online editors like http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert from vb to c# and visa versa.

Hope this helps

Comment: Selecting this answer for answering early and providing a converting tool

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyBase<clTyp, cli> : IMyBase<clType,cli>
    where clTyp : new()
    where cli : class
```

Note that it is not very common to name generic parameters like this. See [What are the type parameter naming guidelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770908/what-are-the-type-parameter-naming-guidelines)

Answer (score 3):

Ooh, this is a tricky one. :)

```
public class MyBase<clTyp, cli> : IMyBase<clTyp, cli> where clTyp : new() where cli : class
```